# Javascript Removing elements from an array based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I am using javascript with knockout.js and I have 2 arrays:

```
self.timesheets = ko.observableArray();
self.selectedTimesheets = ko.observableArray();
```

I load the timesheet data like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Invoice/GetPendingTimesheets',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (timesheetData) {
        self.timesheets(timesheetData);
    }
});
```

Where the timesheets are defined like so:

```
 public class Timesheet
    {
       public  int Id { get; set; }
       public  DateTime WeekStart { get; set; }
    }
```

The selectedTimesheets array keeps track of which checkboxes have been selected

**What I would like to do is remove the elements in self.timesheets that are also in self.selectedtimesheets**, and I am having a mental block figuring out how to do this:

I know there should be something like

```
self.timesheets.remove(function (el) {
               // ????
            });
```

But I just can't think of how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically, you want to iterate through your self.timesheets array and compare each item's id to the ids in self.selectedtimesheets. If the ids match, you want to remove that item from self.timesheets.

Or push all items from both arrays into one new array and remove duplicates.

But since you're using Knockout, if you run the compareArrays utility function:

```
    var differences = ko.utils.compareArrays(self.timesheets, self.selectedtimesheets);
```

differences will now be an array of only the different values.